# jQuery remove div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get my jQuery right to remove a div when I delete something

Code is:

```
<div class="amend_order" data-item_key="1367264719mz7">
    <p>Home Made Ice Cream</p>
    <p class="small_text">Pistachio</p>
    <p>
        <a class="edit_item ui-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</a>
        ----
        <a class="deleter ui-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have tried using

```
$(this).closest('div').remove();
```

unfortunately this does not work.

Basically there is a list of several `divs` and I just want them to disappear when clicked.

Comment: I think you need to show more of your javascript.

Comment: Which element are you working on?

Comment: We can't successfully answer this question without more javascript context.  In specific, what is `this`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B5vP2/ is this you are trying to do? if so your code works

Comment: It work's see this - http://jsfiddle.net/9XsSB/

Comment: I cant get your issue to duplicate. Works fine for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/yWP3z/

Comment: Hmm -`this` should refer to the element that is clicked - `$(document).on('click', '.deleter', function(){ //ajax bit deletes from db then on success should delete the specific div }`

Comment: think I have found the problem - I needed to pass the context of `this` into the ajax success function.

Comment: In your Ajax success this would be jquery ajax object, so you need to use $.proxy to bind the context of `this` to the element clicked.

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.deleter', function(){
    $.ajax({settings:....
            success: $.proxy(function(){ $(this).closest('div').remove();},this)
   
});

Comment: I used `var that=this; $.ajax({type:"POST", url:url, data:data, context:that, success:function(return_data){...` then just changed the reference to `this` to `that`.

Comment: @Sideshow You could've just used `context: this`

Comment: I suppose so - I got it from another post :)

Answer (score 5):

If your container divs are dynamically added, you need to use event delegation. Try this:

```
$("#container").on("click", ".amend_order .deleter", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/m6jVP/

If they're added dynamically, then the event binding won't actually find any elements and therefore won't execute when they're clicked. This event handling runs for any elements inside of `#container` that match the selector `.amend_order .deleter` when they are clicked.

You can replace `#container` with a selector that matches a stable (static) element containing these divs you're targeting, using `document` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="amend_order" data-item_key="1367264719mz7">
    <p>Home Made Ice Cream</p>
    <p class="small_text">Pistachio</p>
    <p>
    <a class="edit_item ui-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Edit</a>
    ----
    <a class="deleter ui-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete</a>
</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.deleter').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
})
```

Live sample http://jsfiddle.net/Ny346/

Answer (score 0):

Try pointing to the div:

```
$('div.amend_order').click(function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

or when clicking on the delete button:

```
$('a.deleter.ui-link').click(function(){
   $(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: This would work as long as the event bubbles. The only thing I would add is to check that the original target of the event was the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.deleter').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove;
})
```

[Live Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sqNgy/)